# How to return PK from insert query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with sequence:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('a_seq'::regclass),
  X integer,
  Y integer,
  Z boolean default false,
  CONSTRAINT A_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have an insert statment in function as follows:

```
insert into A(x,y) select $1,getdig();
```

i want this insert to return the `id` the row was given to a function varabile called `A_id`

It should be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bbb(m integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare 
     A_id  int;
begin
    insert into A(x,y) select $1,getdig() RETURNING id into A_id;

     actions using  A_id like:
     update A set z=True where id=A_id;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `insert into A(x,y) select $1,getdig() RETURNING id`

Comment: It should be `insert into A(x,y) select $1,getdig() RETURNING id into A_id ` bt it says ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into"

Comment: Please post the **complete** source of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `select`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bbb(m integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare 
     A_id  int;
begin
    insert into A(x,y) 
    values ($1,getdig()) 
    RETURNING id into A_id;

    -- actions using  A_id like:
    update A set z=True where id=A_id;

    return a_id; -- don't forget to return something!
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the returning clause:

```
with i as (
      insert into A(x,y)
          select $1, getdig()
          returning id
     )
select *
from i;
```

Technically, the CTE is not necessary.  But I prefer that queries that return values start with `SELECT`.

Comment: where do I put the `into A_id`?

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. This query is inside a function.. i need the returning id of the insert for further actions in the function. How can I access it if i don't save it?

Comment: @java : The problem is that you fail to realize that you (probably) don't *need* a function. Gordon assumes so (and so do I) . But again: you didn't show the rest of your function.

Comment: @joop The function is going to be 50+- rows long, I just posted the issue I faced with the function.